# Unwanted behavior when scrolling on mobile devices (add / remove classes based on viewport size)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My code adds or removes classes based on the viewport size. Everything works fine on the desktop version. Even when resize the browser window, everything works fine. However, I have the following problem on mobile devices (for example iPhone - Safari):

If I open the readmoresection, it closes again as soon as I scroll the page up or down (sometimes only after a few seconds). What can this behavior be and why does it work in the desktop version but not on mobile devices?

Here is my code:

HTML Template:

```
<div class="description" >
    <h2 class="sectionheading">Information for <?= $entry->field('title')->value() ?></h2>
    <div class="readmore readmoresection" itemprop="description"><?= $entry->field('description')->value() ?></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function onResizeReadMoreLayout(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 900) {
                $('.readmoresection span.handler').show();
                $('.readmoresection').addClass('reduced');
                if($('.readmoresection').hasClass('reduced')){
                    $('.readmoresection span.handler').html(' » Weiterlesen');
                }else{
                    $('.readmoresection span.handler').html(' » Schließen');
                    $('.readmoresection').removeClass('reduced');
                }
            }
            else{
                $('.readmoresection span.handler').hide();
                $('.readmoresection').removeClass('reduced');
        }  
}

// initial state
 onResizeReadMoreLayout();
 // on resize
 $(window).on('resize', onResizeReadMoreLayout);
```

Here is the working live version: [CLICK](https://www.academyofsports.de/de/fitness/fitness-c-lizenz.html). Check out the read more functionality after the headline "INFORMATIONEN ZUM FERNSTUDIUM FITNESS C-LIZENZ"

Comment: Does else block of following condition ever gets called `if($('.readmoresection').hasClass('reduced'))` ?

Comment: Please provide us with a working jsfiddle. Plus what @sandyJoshi said is correct. You are adding the class before the 'hasClass' check, so it will always return true, thus, the 'else' part will never run.

Comment: @sandyJoshi It gets called, because the innerHTML is changing from "Weiterlesen" to "Schließen". I have updated my answer and added the link to the website where the functionality can be seen.

Comment: @scooterlord I have updated my answer and added the link to the website where the functionality can be seen. On desktop everything is working fine (on every viewport size). But if you call it on a mobile device, then the error described above occurs.

Comment: I don't see any listen for click event in your code

Comment: Currently I am on mobile so can not debug your site and see

Comment: scrolling in iPhone will (almost) always cause a lot of resize due to the top and bottom menu bars, especially when in landscape mode - or by orientationchange moreover with wrong values. Try to throttle your resize handler function, but first of all - as @sandyJoshi said, change that piece of code to be more browser-friendly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `readmore` section closes as soon as you scroll up on iOS because the address bar changes height and/or bottom action bar appears, thus causing a window resize. However, here is another proposed solution that is based purely on CSS, so not only will you avoid your issue, but avoid unnecessary bloat from your Javascript.

Here is the proposed solution. I tried to use similar classes with your code so that it makes more sense.

Also, as a side-note, whenever possible try to reduce Javascript listeners to a minimum for performance reasons, especially ones like `resize` or `scroll`.

Last, but not least, depending on the browser and the browser scrollbar type, `$(window).width()` is prone to producing different results - aka `900px` versus `900px + scrollbar width`.

HTML:

```
<div class="readmoresection">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Gravida neque convallis a cras semper auctor neque vitae. Magna sit
    amet purus gravida quis blandit. Dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at. Leo a diam sollicitudin tempor. Consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit
    amet. Quam elementum pulvinar etiam non. Ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean. Eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper. Faucibus ornare suspendisse
    sed nisi lacus. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc. Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus. Egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque.
  </p>
  <p class="content-hidden">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Gravida neque convallis a cras semper auctor neque vitae. Magna sit
    amet purus gravida quis blandit. Dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at. Leo a diam sollicitudin tempor. Consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit
    amet. Quam elementum pulvinar etiam non. Ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean. Eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper. Faucibus ornare suspendisse
    sed nisi lacus. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc. Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus. Egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque.
  </p>
  <span class="handler"><span class="handler-opened">Toggle close</span><span class="handler-hidden">Toggle open</span></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width:900px) {
  .content-hidden {
    display: none;
  }
  .handler-opened {
    display: none;
  }
  .opened .handler-opened {
    display: block;
  }
  .opened .handler-hidden {
    display: none;
  }
  .opened .content-hidden {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width:901px) {
  .content-hidden {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .handler {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Javasript:

```
$('.readmoresection').on('click', 'span.handler', function() {
  $(this).closest('.readmoresection').toggleClass('opened');
});
```

And here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/scooterlord/dLjygyrj/

Comment: After all my unsuccessful attempts this is the best solution. Many Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help you out.